# Assets2 subfolders have gone missing

Tags: pixelandtonic, assets

A recent import using Solspace importer where I just wanted to update a standard file field (NOT an asset field) has had the unfortunate side effect that in my assets file manager and assets fields all subfolders have gone missing.
When I try to recreate a subfolder I get an alert telling me the folder already exists, but it's not visible in the asset file manager.
All the data that's in the entry form is still correct but when trying to upload a file all subfolders have gone missing as well as in the assets file manager.
Any suggestions on how to get these back?

Comment: Have you checked that Assets is still enabled? The Module, Extension, and Field type. Sometimes these things can have a small side effect.

Comment: All 3 are indeed enabled.

Comment: Can you provide a few screenshots of what you're seeing? Also, what version of EE and Assets are you running?

Comment: EE and Assets latest versions.

Comment: http://www.stookstudio.com/debug/screenshot_01.jpg shows the assets view
http://www.stookstudio.com/debug/screenshot_03.jpg shows the subfolders in Transmit

Comment: Hi, Erwin - what I would do in this case is to make a dev environment and update one entry and see what happens there.  That should help you track down why the import is touching Assets.  Can you also let us know version numbers, as opposed to "latest"?  Also, have you run an 'update indexes" operation?

Comment: I see you've also emailed us and Andris is going to look. We'll make sure to keep this updated. Thank you!

Comment: Lisa; EE2.5.5 and Assets2.1 - update indexes was the first thing I tried without success. Will wait to hear from P&T tech support, thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm a similar issue here

In our case updating Assets to 2.1 made subfolders disappear. However database was intact. Hence the error when trying to recreate same folders.

Solution was to

1. Create a dummy folder
2. Move all disappeared files/folders into the dummy folder
3. Update indexes & delete references
4. Rename dummy folder with the old folder name
5. Update indexes & delete references again

Hope this helps

Comment: Cem, you have this all fixed up? If you have this site in the state prior to being fixed, I'd be happy for us to troubleshoot it directly.